# How to fix this Angular error: Argument expression expected.ts(1135)?

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, angular7, crud

Im following a crud tutorial, everything is ok, I checked code is equal to tutorial code, but I received this error code Argument expression expected. ts(1335), the error it appears on the submit method onSubmit(), I left a comment on the exact line, thanks beforehand

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {StudentsService} from '../students.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Students } from '../students';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add',
  templateUrl: './add.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add.component.css']
})

export class AddComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private _studentService: StudentsService,
    private router: Router
    ) { 

  }
  addForm: FormGroup;

  ngOnInit() {

    this.addForm = this.formBuilder.group({

       fName: ['', Validators.required],
       lName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(9)]],
       email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(30)]]
    });
  }


  onSubmit() {
    //console.log(this.addForm.value);
    this._studentService.createStudent(this.addForm.value)
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.router.navigate(['view']);
    },
  } //the error it appears in this line

  }
```

Comment: the parentheses are incorrect

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
onSubmit() {

    this._studentService.createStudent(this.addForm.value)
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.router.navigate(['view']);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Good, now the error it moves to the last 
onSubmit() { 
//console.log(this.addForm.value); this._studentService.createStudent(this.addForm.value)
 .subscribe(data => { this.router.navigate(['view']); 
 }), 
} //to this

Expression expected ts(1109)
} expected

Comment: use semi colon instead of comma after `{ this.router.navigate(['view']); })`

Comment: Perfection, thank you  brother, people who put the soul